# ConcurrentModificationException in MutableStateFlow Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I get `ConcurrentModificationException` when updating / using `MutableStateFlow` at the same time. How to prevent that?

Code snippet:

```kotlin
class SearchViewModel() : ViewModel() {

val searchState = MutableStateFlow(SearchState())

private fun getItems() = viewModelScope.launch {
    ....
    object : Callback<Results> {
        override fun publish(items: Results): Boolean {

            searchState.value = searchState.value.copy(   // <--- ConcurrentModificationException at emit() function
                currentItems = items
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun ScreenContent(viewModel: SearchViewModel) {

    val state by viewModel.searchState.collectAsState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        // \/ ConcurrentModificationException here sometimes as well
        state.currentItems.forEachIndexed { index, searchRowItemData ->
            SearchRowItem(searchRowItemData, index == state.currentItems.lastIndex) {
                onItemClicked(searchRowItemData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is that I update and iterate the searchState property at the same time. But how to solve that ?

Comment: what is `SearchState`? is it immutable? (if not, it should be)

Comment: Its data class in viewmodel

Comment: but is it immutable?

Comment: yes it is immutable

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the issue was changing the dispatcher from `Main` with is default one if not set, to some background one, i.e.: `IO`

`private fun getItems() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {`

Worked like a charm